# What's the purpose of the command in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongoDB and i have the following query as follows "db.runCommand( { addshard : "sf103", maxSize:100000 } );" Why we are using sf103 If i use this command in my Environment i am Getting following errors>>> db.runCommand( { addshard : "sf103", maxSize:100000 } );
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "couldn't connect to new shard dbconnectionpool: connect failed sf103 : "
}
>

Here, The Sf103 represents what???? Please help me.......

Advance Thanks,
Kumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addshard takes the first parameter as "serverhostname[:port]". sf103 is a example host name they specified. What is the mongo host you want to add to the cluster. Please read the doc to understand how to configure the mongo cluster.
[Mongo sharded cluster config](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Configuring+Sharding)

--Sai

Comment: Thank you Sai...The mongo host which i want to add to the cluster is "Mongod shard"........The maxsize specified here [maxSize:100000] is in bytes or Megabytes??Can u provide your email-id so that i can clarify some doubts......

Comment: Mongo shard is the host name? And the maxSize is the disk size in MBs. Mongo has good doc. Please refer it.. Emails, I am more of snailmail guy. Never registered any email :)

Comment: I mean the mongod-shardserver. I am running mongod shard in my localhost..Thank You....